# File not found exception getting while import export table in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i am running this command **"hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver export 'temp' /dump"** 
but i am getting exception Actually i have to export table and import in different database.

```
2016-06-15 17:56:49,365 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2016-06-15 17:56:49,463 INFO  [main] mapreduce.Export: versions=1, starttime=0, endtime=9223372036854775807, keepDeletedCells=false
2016-06-15 17:56:49,745 WARN  [main] mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil: The hbase-prefix-tree module jar containing PrefixTreeCodec is not present.  Continuing without it.
2016-06-15 17:56:50,058 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
2016-06-15 17:56:50,058 INFO  [main] jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2016-06-15 17:56:50,289 INFO  [main] mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/staging/abhay1268840199/.staging/job_local1268840199_0001
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$17.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export.main(Export.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.run(ProgramDriver.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:153)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: can you try to run from different node of the cluster? I think its class path issue? I got this but I tried to run from different node of the cluster it was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is definitely common environment issue. Please try to export classpath first and then try to run Export command

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`:`hbase classpath`
java -cp "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH/*"
```

second command java -cp (is for debugging purpose)will expand each jar file in the classpath to see whether the missing jar exists in this list or not...

Another quick solution (not preferable but for the time being kind of) : copy the jar hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar to that location.

Comment: hi thanks for reply, but i have already checked /usr/local/hbase/lib/ folder there is already jar available

Comment: have you checked hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hbase/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar

Comment: Hii sorry to say, but i am new to hadoop and hbase, so can you tell me in which path i need to check???

Comment: can you try hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hbase/lib/ and paste result here

Comment: 16/06/16 11:36:09 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: `hdfs://localhost:54310/usr/local/hbase/lib/': No such file or directory

Comment: have you tried above command in hadoop classpath i.e `hbase classpath`

Comment: NativeLibraryChecker is a tool to check whether native libraries are loaded correctly. You can launch NativeLibraryChecker as follows: hadoop checknative -a

Comment: i got this able
Native library checking:
hadoop:  false 
zlib:    false 
snappy:  false 
lz4:     false 
bzip2:   false 
openssl: false 
16/06/16 11:44:36 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1

Comment: ok can you execute the same Export command in another node of the cluster

Comment: same erorr getting

Comment: can you print the command or shell script ? are you using -libjars option ?

Comment: Thanks for help, i manually copied all jar file from lib folder to hdfs, now its working...

Comment: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/ also have a look for permanent solution.